# How to block a page from any content modifications in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365

We have several pages in our Office 365 modern pages. Those contents are editable meaning any user can edit those pages. However, sometimes those pages need to be blocked from any content modification?

How to block a page from any content modifications in the Office 365 modern site? Should it be an admin feature or contributor feature?

Can we get this using OOTB SP (out of the box SharePoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set page-item-level permissions to lock those pages down to certain users.

- If you have a specific set of users that should always retain contribute rights on those pages, you should first [create a SharePoint Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions#create-a-group) to hold those users.
- Find the page in the sitepages library that you want to protect.
- Click the vertical ellipses button to open the context menu and choose "Manage Access" (see screenshot)
  [image: screenshot of manage access circled in the context menu]
- In the right-hand pane that appears with permissions, click the "Advanced" link at the bottom.
- On the Advanced Permissions page, click the "Stop Inheriting Permissions" button (see screenshot).
  [image: Screenshot of the Stop Inheriting Permissions button]
- Now you can control the permissions on this page by removing the site-level Members group or other permissions and/or adding whatever individuals or groups should still have access.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer